# How to properly use Router inside Router in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I'm struggling with creating routes using "react-router-dom".
The default "Page1" is being displayed:
[as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ9D9.png),
but I'm getting a blank page when switching to "Page2" or "Page3".

I'll be glad if someone will be able to take a look at my code. Thanks!

App.js:

```
import Layout from "./Layout";
import Login from "./Login";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={"/"} component={Layout} />
        <Route path={"/login"} component={Login} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Login.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: "1",
    height: "100%",
  },
}));

const Login = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <div className={classes.root}>Login</div>;
};

export default Login;
```

Layout.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Header from "./Header";
import Menu from "./Menu";
import Page1 from "./Page1";
import Page2 from "./Page2";
import Page3 from "./Page3";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    overflow: "hidden",
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
}));

export default function Layout() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Menu />
      <Grid container direction="column">
        <Grid item xs>
          <Header />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Page1} />
            <Route path="/page2" component={Page2} />
            <Route path="/page3" component={Page3} />
          </Switch>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Menu.js

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    height: "100vh",
    width: "90px",
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.menu,
    textAlign: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "lightblue",
  },
}));

const StyledListItem = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexDirection: "column",
    textAlign: "center",
    opacity: 0.8,
  },
}))(ListItem);

const MainNavMenu = (props) => {
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  let history = useHistory();

  // Navigate between pages
  const navigate = (text, index) => {
    setSelectedIndex(index);
    if ("page1" === text) {
      history.push("/");
    } else if ("page2" === text) {
      history.push("/page2");
    } else {
      history.push("/page3");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <List>
        {["page1", "page2", "page3"].map((text, index) => (
          <StyledListItem
            button
            key={index}
            selected={selectedIndex === index}
            onClick={() => {
              navigate(text, index);
            }}
          >
            <ListItemText primary={text} />
          </StyledListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MainNavMenu;
```

Page1.js (All pages look the same):

```
function Page1() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Page 1</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Page1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app needs to know that it should handle `/page2` and `/page1` through the `Layout` component.  Right now it does not because your `Route` only matches `exact path={"/"}`.

You can remove the `exact` to send all traffic through `Layout`.  Since the first match is used, you always want to have your `Route` components listed from most specific to least specific.  Without `exact`, the `Route` for `Layout` now belongs at the bottom of the list.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={"/login"} component={Login} />
        <Route path={"/"} component={Layout} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

---

The paths in your `Layout` don't match up with the ones in `Menu`.  You have no `/page3` in `Layout`.

Layout:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Page1} />
<Route path="/page1" component={Page2} />
<Route path="/page2" component={Page3} />
```

Menu:

```
{["page1", "page2", "page3"].map((text, index) => (
```

Likely you want to change `Layout` like this:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Page1} />
<Route path="/page2" component={Page2} />
<Route path="/page3" component={Page3} />
```

---

I personally would do the navigation with the react-router-dom `Link` component but you would need to handle your styling differently.

Comment: Thanks! I removed the exact and moved the default path to the bottom and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

There is no page1 or page2 route in your code. That's why you get a blank page.

Comment: I forgot to add the Menu.js code and updated the paths in Layout.js and still not working

Comment: You need to put "/" before your path names. like ```path="/page1"```

Answer (score 0):

Remove exact in app component.Since you put exact, its not switching to nested components.

```
<Switch>
      <Route path={"/"} component={Layout} />
      <Route path={"/login"} component={Login} />
</Switch>
```

**Edit to the comment**

Just name the route instead of blank e.g "/home" and redirect blank route to home.
Like this

```
<Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" > <Redirect to="/home" /> </Route>
      <Route path={"/home"} component={Layout} />
      <Route path={"/login"} component={Login} />
</Switch>
```

Mostly page1,page2,page3 will work. If not , implement "useRoutematch" and put paths in `<Route>` in Layout.js

Comment: Now I can navigate between "/page1" "/page2" and "/page3" but when I navigate to "/login" (by changing the url) the Login screen isn't displayed. Instead I see Layout.js with no page

Answer (score 0):

```
 import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
 import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
  <Router>
    <Fragment>
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
        <Route component={Routes} />
      </Switch>
    </Fragment>
  </Router>
```